# Fail sending big file using DefaultHttpClient

Tags: java, android, networking, connection, android-networking

I'm trying to transfer big file to the server using httpput.
However, I can't to transfer big files. I get IOException with error message: "I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer".
I'm using the code:

```
    // create authenticate client
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

    // create HTTP put with the file
    HttpPut httpPut = new HttpPut(url);
    final File recordingFile = new File(mDir, mName);
    FileEntity entity = new FileEntity(recordingFile, "binary/octet-stream");
    entity.setChunked(true);
    httpPut.setEntity(entity);
    httpPut.addHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    httpPut.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/zip");

    // Execute
    HttpResponse res = client.execute(httpPut);
    int statusCode = res.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

Comment: Are you sure your HTTP server supports the PUT method? Maybe you should try using the more common POST method instead, i.e. change `HttpPut` to `HttpPost` in your code.

Comment: Yes. I can HTTP PUT file. Just a small file. Replacing to HttpPost give the same result.

Comment: Have you checked your server logs for the traffic generated by the client? Is it redirecting the PUT for instance?

Comment: what kind of server are you talking to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When sending file through http remember that your server http has a max-limit to dimension of the file.

If i'm not wrong the default value is 2MB: but you can change this on the configuration file of the server (PHP).

The file to check is php.ini.

Open the file and search for 'upload_max_filesize = 2M': simply change 2 with the dimension you need for your project and save.

That's all!

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to change the maximum Request size in the web.config file.

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="110" maxRequestLength="8192" />
```

Comment: Sorry, you totally missed that this is for a java environment instead of something by Microsoft (i.e. ASP.NET)